# Excel formula change values if its formula in cell but no value in that cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have this formula in cell:

```
=IFERROR((SUMIF( C9:C20; "<>"; E9:E20)-SUMIF(E9:E20; "<>"; C9:C20))/SUMIF(E9:E20; "<>"; C9:C20); 0)
```

And for example if in cell E19 is nothing but just the VLOOKUP formula that is going to return me blank if no values were found the formula from above will also calculate the cell E19 but with blank in it.

Comment: Your formula refers to the range "E9:E20", which contains cell "E19", so if the content of "E19" changes, then the result of your formula changes. This is normal Excel behaviour. What don't you understand about this? (Oh, in what cell is that formula located?)

Comment: I understand everything there, what I want is to make the formula not to change if blank is in cell E19 (but in cell E19 is VLOOKUP formula)

Comment: How do you get a blank in a `VLookup()` formula result? Are you looking for blanks? Anyway, there is an `IsBlank()` function, can you use this?

Comment: Example of your data and expected result would help to understand your issue

Comment: I have made here a short video on what is happening.
https://imgur.com/a/JT27Tgg

Comment: SUMIF(E9:E20; "<>"; C9:C20) sums C9:C20 where E9:E20 is blank. If you have formula in E column which returns for example "", it is not blank. Leave A1 blank, and put something like ="" in B1. Both looks like they are empty, but =ISBLANK(A1) will return TRUE, while =ISBLANK(B1) will return FALSE

Comment: you could perhaps use `CELL("type")` which returns "b" for blanks, "l" for text and "v" for all other. There is also a formula called `=ISFORMULA(reference)` that checks if the referenced cell contains a formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question lacks a bit of explanation of what you're trying to accomplish and what your current formula does versus what you expect it to do.

I think you mean to get the following logic:

`A`: If a cell in `C9:C20` contains a number than sum the values in `E9:E20`

`B`: If a cell in `E9:E20` contains a number than sum the values in `C9:C20`

With that logic calculate the following:
`(A-B)/B`

You could accomplish that using:
`=LET(B,SUM(TOCOL(IFS(E9:E20,C9:C20),2)),(SUM(TOCOL(IFS(C9:C20,E9:E20),2))-B)/B)`

for older excel than Office 365:

```
=(SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR(IF(C9:C20,E9:E20),0))
  -SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR(IF(E9:E20,C9:C20),0))
  )
  /SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR(IF(E9:E20,C9:C20),0))
```