# Excel calculates formula even if cell is blank

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

I have this formula:

```
=IFERROR(SUM(E9:E20)/COUNTA(E9:E20); 0)*12
```

Which calculates the values in cells e9:e20 but in some cells I have blank but just the VLOOKUP formula.
I have made a short video to understand better my problem.

Video: https://imgur.com/a/pNPu44T

Comment: You have already asked and got answer to similar question. Empty string (for example "") returned by lookup is not blank https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77200087/excel-formula-change-values-if-its-formula-in-cell-but-no-value-in-that-cell

Comment: ok i understand that but how can I make this formula to not calculate the blank:
=IFERROR(SUM(E9:E20)/COUNTA(E9:E20); 0)*12

Comment: use an if() to test for a blank, if true then don't do the calculation: if(a1="","",sum_calc) or test for a value greater than 0 like: if(a1>0,sum_calc,"")

Comment: Change COUNTA to COUNT which counts numeric values so will not count empty string or blank: =IFERROR(SUM(E9:E20)/COUNT(E9:E20); 0)*12

Comment: it worked changing the counta to count thanks @user11222393

Answer (score 0):

Change COUNTA to COUNT which counts numeric values so will not count empty string or blank: =IFERROR(SUM(E9:E20)/COUNT(E9:E20); 0)*12

Thanks: @user11222393